# Link to a slug for a resource

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have a `Country`:

```
mix phx.gen.html Location Country countries name slug:unique
```

For linking to a `Country` I'd like to use the `slug` and not the `id`. How can I achieve it that this code will link to the `slug` (e.g. `http://localhost:4000/countries/germany`)?

```
<%= link "Show", to: country_path(@conn, :show, country), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

Comment: Did you try using `country.slug` in `country_path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the [`Phoenix.Param`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Param.html) protocol for the module. The easiest way to do this is to add the following before the `schema "..."` in your module:

```
@derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :slug}
schema "..." do
  ...
end
```

Now instead of `id`, the `slug` field will be used when generating links from the URL helpers generated by Phoenix.